# "APKs are not allowed for this application" when submitting an expo build to play store

Tags: android, react-native, google-api, expo, fastlane

I'm trying to submit a build to Google play internal testing but it fails with the error:
`Google Api Error: Invalid request - APKs are not allowed for this application`

I am running the following commands:

```
eas build --profile development --platform android # works successfully
eas submit -p android
```

When running submit, `Select a build from EAS` doesn't work (returns `Couldn't find any Android builds for this project on EAS servers. It looks like you haven't run 'eas build' yet.`), so I provide the build ID from the build command. I have set `buildType` to `app-bundle` but it would still return the error.
In the submit logs, I notice this:

`skip_upload_apk                 | false`

Can I change it to `true` and will that help?
I have manually updated a build prior to running eas submit. Possibly related issue: during manual upload, it wasn't accepting the APK file as well, so I had to upload AAB.

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.37.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "releaseChannel": "default",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      },
      "env":  {
        ... // my env configs
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "version": "0.0.5",
    "scheme": "myscheme",
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "sentry-expo"
    ],
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you may want to post this to https://forums.expo.dev. also, it's generally useful to elaborate on what "doesn't work" means, eg: in "When running submit, Select a build from EAS doesn't work" it's not clear what you are saying.

Comment: It wasn't the main issue, so I skipped the details. But I've updated it now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I have two apps with identical eas.json files - one built an AAB with no problems, the second app is building an APK and I can't get the initial, manual upload to work.

Answer (score 6):

As of August 2021, the Play Store only allows new apps to upload AAB files.  Old apps are grandfathered into allowing apks for a while.  Short of a specific deal with Google (good luck with that), if you have a new app you will need to upload an aab instead.

Comment: Came across this info as well but what I'd like to understand is if this makes eas-cli obsolete or if there is some config that would let uploading an AAB

Comment: when you run EAS Build, by default AAB is generated, except when you explicitly set buildType to APK or "distribution": "internal. if you do a build with your production profile, it will be an AAB

Comment: @brentvatne tried it using production profile as well but same error. in google console though, it's set to "internal testing". would that have anything to do with it? but if it does, then it means I can't do eas submission during testing?

Comment: you should post to https://forums.expo.dev and provide more information, such as a link to your build page.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your development build is building an apk that's only meant for internal distribution. Once you remove `"distribution": "internal",` that's nested under `"development"` and run the build process again, it'll create an .aab that you'll be able to submit to Play Store.

You can find more information at the [Play Console Help Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859152?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

The eas.json within the root of your project file contains 3 different profile configurations. Development, Preview, or Production. These can be changed by issuing the following command:

```
eas build --profile production
```

The production profile doesn't contain the "distribution": "internal" configuration so it will submit the correct build App Store.

https://docs.expo.dev/build/automating-submissions/